# Move LXD container to other storage

Tags: linux, storage, containers, btrfs, lxd

I have an issue with my current `storage.img` file (btrfs). I had 2TB data inside a container and so the storage.img got 2TB large. After this I deleted everything, leaving me with 100GB of real data. The problem is now, that the storage.img did not shrink itself to 100GB. It is still 2TB big.

I have created another storage `newstorage.img` (btrfs) in LXD with the command `lxc storage create newstorage` but I don't know how to transfer the containers to the new storage **the right way** so I can delete the old `storage.img` and reclaim my HDD space.

I tried things like manually mounting the two imgs and doing `cp -R /one/* /new/` but then I cannot start the containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "hack" that resolves the issue.

The problem is that `lxc storage create newstorage` does create a 15GB image per default. This value cannot be changed.

One has to have access to another Linux machine with a fresh install of LXD and execute `lxd init` there. Select btrfs, a loop device size of the desired new capacity of the image and the image name. Now copy that new storage.img to the server.

The steps to copy the contents are:

1. Shut down all containers
2. Reboot machine
3. Mount old storage.img to /mnt/oldstorage
4. Mount new storage.img to /mnt/newstorage
5. Execute sudo cp -rpv /mnt/oldstorage /mnt/newstorage
6. Move old storage.img out of the /var/lib/lxd/disks/ folder
7. Move new storage.img to /var/lib/lxd/disks/
8. Reboot machine
9. Start all containers

**Edit**:
This method works fine as long as you don't delete any existing containers. LXD does create a subvolume for each container. If you want to keep the ability to delete existing containers you should create a subvolume for each container.

```
btrfs subvolume create [-i <qgroupid>] [<dest>/]<name>
```

Answer (score 3):

No tricks needed:

```
lxc stop container_name
lxc move container_name temp_container_name -s new_storage_pool
lxc move temp_container_name container_name
lxc start container_name
```

Credits: https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/how-to-move-containers-to-a-new-storage-pool-on-the-same-host/2798

Comment: I wish there was a way to override the "correct" answer.  The one which you delineated is correct and works for all situations.  I moved from a ceph cluster to zfs and used this technique.  The other "hack" would not have worked.